# How to hide @Html kind of input tags?

Tags: c#

I want to hide the following html input tag. So how to do it with these kind of @Html tags?

**@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })**

Comment: question is not clear. You want a hidden field using @Html or something else?

Comment: next time, please use better tags :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
```